# % Relation of the Total

Tags: statistics

I have two factories

```
               Production              Target
Factory A       121.58                 126.41
Factory B       110.62                 106.45
```

If you calculate the % based on its target

```
Formula (Production - Target) / Target
```

We have a result of

```
Factory A       -3.82%
Factory B        3.92%
```

Here is the question

Why if you add the % you get **`0.096%`**
While when you Add Production and Target and get the % contribution of the Total you end up with a different Answer **`-0.28%`**

In other words

> ((Production A + Production B) - (Target A + Target B)) / (Target A +
>   Target B)

is not equal to

> ((Production A - Target A)/Target A) + (Production B - Target
>   B)/Target B))

Should they produce the same result?

Comment: Did you mean to average the original percents instead of simply adding them?  If both factors exceeded target by 1% you wouldn't argue that together they exceeded by 2%.   Regardless of that, though, you can't simply add (or average) percents without adjusting for sample size.  If A spends 1 out of a total 10 and B spends 5,000 out of a total 10,000 then the overall spending is completely determined by what B spent, simply because the numbers are larger.

Comment: Along these lines, it may be worth reading about Simpson's paradox.  It can happen, for example, that batter A has a better batting average than B in both June and July, but B has a better average over the two months taken together. Things like that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox

Comment: @lulu in this case I was asking why there is a difference when you add the production and target and get the relative % against the target and when you just add the %

Comment: But percentages don't add, even if the sample sizes match.  If, say, on Tuesday, I win one of two contests (so my Tuesday percent is 50%) and then on Wednesday I lose both of two contests (so my Wed. percent is 0%) , my total percent is 25% (not 50% + 0%).  True, my total is the average because in this case the sample sizes match. If, instead, on Wed. I lost all of three contests my Wed average would again be 0% but this time my total percentage would be 20%.

Comment: Straight to the point. Thank you.